# RDD issues whith SparkSession

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am new to spark scala and practicing now on my own. can you please help in resolving the issue

> could not resolve symbol SparkSession in scala

when I `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` in scala to practice RDD and transformations.

Comment: Are you using SBT or Maven and have you added spark-core and spark-sql as a library dependencies to your project?

Comment: I am using Maven. I did not add spark-sql as dependencies.

Comment: If you want to practice, I would recommend you to use **SBT** and add the dependencies _(You will need `spark-sql` too)_ so you can open a shell _(with the `sbt console` command)_ where you can import the classes and play with them in a local environment _(similar to the `spark-shell`)_. IMHO, if you are learning is better to have an interactive environment, rather than compile, execute, fail. - BTW, I wrote a [small introductory **Spark** tutorial](https://github.com/pslcorp/spark-scala-workshop) for my coworkers - in a humble way I hope it will serve you :)

Comment: @Sekhar I added an answer to show an example of pom.xml and sbt.build you can use it and change the project and version names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you miss the dependencies, So, if you use Maven you can add the below in your pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.project.lib</groupId>
    <artifactId>PROJECT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But if you use sbt you use the below sample in your sbt.build

```
name := "SparkTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion

)
```

Comment: If you are using `provided`, then both **core** and **sql** should be too.

Comment: I removed provided to but it will depend on his own cluster or environment setup.

Comment: I am not sure but I think my answer will solve this issue